# Seeing what background process is up to

Tags: unix, background-process, command-line-interface

I currently have a background process on my unix server that's running hours longer than it should be.

I can't remember the command to allow me to see the output of a background process. I'll remember to bookmark this answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What also might be useful if you're uncertain whether it's doing anything at all, is use 'strace'.

If your app is the 'dhcpd' service, run `ps ax | grep [d]hcpd`

```
$ ps axufw | grep [d]hcpd
dhcpd    21645  0.0  0.1  19156  4956 ?        Ss   Oct02   0:00 /usr/sbin/dhcpd -f -q -4 -pf /run/dhcp-server/dhcpd.pid -cf /etc/ltsp/dhcpd.conf
```

Your PID is 21645, so you'd run `sudo strace -p 21645`. Or drop the 'sudo' if you're root already.

It will get the system calls from your application in real time and tell you precisely what your program is doing.

Note: Wrap a letter of the grep command in a bracket to strain out the grep command itself.

Answer (score 2):

As a follow up to Mariano Montañez Ureta.

If you can see the task in the `jobs` window, all you should be able to see something like this:

```
$ jobs
[1]+  Running                 tail -f .ssh/known_hosts &
```

If you then use the `fg` command coupled with the job number you can bring that to the foreground, i.e. `fg %1` would bring my `tail` command to the foreground. You can also use the `fg` command with a PID.

Comment: hmm..does ubuntu not have the 'jobs' command? I get a command not found.

Comment: I just tested on an Ubuntu box, and it did have `jobs`. I tested on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: @Ian: `jobs` is a Bash built-in. If you don't have it, you're doing other weird things with your system. The jobs command has been around almsost forever.

Comment: Bizarre...it's a Mythbuntu 11.04 install. Absolutely does not find 'jobs'...perhaps my computer's unemployed. :-)

Comment: In any case, you can still forground a task using `fg <pid>`. Alternatively you can use strace as suggested by Adrian.

Answer (score 1):

use fg wich means foreground :)

Answer (score 0):

```
tail -f whatever-file-the-process-is-writing-to.txt
```

Comment: the process is not writing to any file. I need to see what's it would be outputting to screen if it was a foreground process. I've done it before, just blanking.

Comment: If it isn't sending any output anywhere, how do you expect to see it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I did it a year ago...the command enabled you to see what it would be outputting to the terminal it was in the foreground.